# If java has only 3 types of variable then what is Reference Variable

Tags: java

If java has only 3 types of variable then what is Reference Variable

```
class A {
    int x;// it is instance variable 
    A a; // it is also instance variable 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      int x;//now it is local variable 
    A a; // but it is not local why?

    }
}
```

Can any one please guide why reference variable is not part of 3 types of variables i.e

1. Static Variable
2. Instance Variable
3. Local Variable

Comment: Java has only three types of variables in that concept scope wise. (and then there are still the modifiers that make differences). a static variable can be a primitive datatype or an Object (reference), same goes for instance and local variables

Comment: Because these are different categorisations of variables. You do realise that one can categorise things in more than one way, right?

Comment: "but it is not local why?" - it's local. You declare a local variable with the same name as the instance variable (which is usually called a field).

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one way to classifying things. I can say that there are 3 types of people in the world - children (below 18 years old), elderly (age 60+), and adults (everyone else). Your question is like asking

> If there are only children, adults, and elderly, then why is "woman" not a part of those three types of people?

Well, because classifying people according to gender is a different way of classifying people, so the categories don't match up exactly.

In the case of variables, there is the classification according to scope and static-ness. The categories could be:

- local variables
- instance variables (aka instance fields)
- static variables (aka static fields)

Or you can classify them based on the type of the variable - whether the variable's type is a primitive type like `int`, or a reference type like `String` or the `A` class you wrote. The categories could be:

- reference variables
- primitive variables

On the other hand, the Java Language Specification defines [8 kinds of variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.3), and that is *yet* another way of classifying them.

All this is to say that you shouldn't worry too much about how many/what types of variables there are when reading/writing code. The point is about learning how to *describe* these things (like variables) to other people so they understand what you are talking about, rather than putting things into boxes.

Back to your code. If we were to use the two classifications above:

```
class A {
    int x;// primitive instance variable
    A a;  // reference instance variable

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      int x;// primitive local variable
      A a;  // reference local variable

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question you're probably wondering why a reference variable isn't one of the things you're listing a reference variable is not one of the user defined variables by definition, it's more like a C++ pointer, when you declare a Java object, you can make changes to the object's parameters by reference passing

```
   public void test() {
      User user = new User();
      user.setAge(18);
      change(user);
      System.out.println("age:" + user.getAge());
   }
   private void change(User user) {
      user.setAge(19);
   }
```

这个例子实际输出 19